# Why won't windows explorer sort directories under the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' directory by name?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, directory, explorer, temporary-files

When I navigate to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myfirstproject\202aebd2\f0e764e2\assembly\dl3 in Windows explorer, there are 108 folders with 8 character hexadecimal names.  Explorer won't sort this folder by name (or value ).  What gives?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of how it's sorting it and how that's different than what you'd expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* sorting them by name. Unfortunately, it's using a [natural sort](http://www.siao2.com/2006/10/01/778990.aspx) which includes numbers. This means that `99b6...` sorts before `182c...`, because `99 < 182`.

Comment: Such behavior is generally known as *broken*.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same question. I found that you can, at least in XP, set the sort order by adding a registry key.  This should take care of your issue.  Remember to restart Explorer.  You can kill its process and then restart it through Task Manager.

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\    Explorer]
Value Name: NoStrCmpLogical
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (1 = Windows 2000 method)
```

Originally found the answer here:

http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1293/

**Edit:**

Looks like that answer actually comes from a Knowlege Base article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319827

Answer (score 1):

Windows can make directories backed by other directories.  For instance the old-style Temporary Internet Files was backed by 4 separate directories.  Knowing this I'd guess that it's sorting each directory individually instead of the aggregate.

Comment: Do you know of any tools that would allow me to see which directories are being aggregated?  I don't believe I can see this in Procmon/Filemon.

Comment: More specifically, Windows can make explorer namespace folders that aren't backed by filesystem directories at all. The GAC (displayed at `C:\Windows\assembly`) is a case in point.